# How can I count number of pixels in a contour?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, contour

I have a data set of labeled WSI of cancerous tissues. These slides are segmented by considering each class and draw their corresponding contours. I do know the coordinate of each contour in each slide. Since I wanna know the percentage of occurrence of each class in a slide, my question is how I can count number of pixels inside each contour in Python?
Many thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) will help you.

Comment: Just use cv2.contourArea()

Answer (score 0):

You can create a black image of the same size as the original image. The using `cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 1), -1)` you can plot all the contours. The last -1 denotes that the entire contour needs to be filled. Now you use just sum the whole image using `np.sum` to obtain the total number of pixels.